# Allocating memory for a structure array inside another structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I really don't know what the issue is here. The compiler says it's all okay, but when I run it, the executable crashes ( I believe it's a segmentation fault problem ). They say two minds are always better than one, so I hope you guys can find whatever I have missed.

Okay, so it goes this way: I have 2 structures:

```
struct _Color {

    unsigned char r,g,b;
    char *pchars;
}; //typedef to Color in header file

struct _XPM {

    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned char cpp; 
    unsigned int ncolors;
    Color *colta; //collor table
    unsigned int *data[];

}; //typedef to XPM in header file
```

Then, in a function I allocate memory for the XPM structure and then for the Color array inside the XPM structure (I won't write the fail safe code here):

```
XPM *imagine; //received as a parameter
imagine = ( XPM* ) malloc ( sizeof ( XPM ) + sizeof ( unsigned int* ) * width );
imagine -> colta = malloc ( ncolors * sizeof ( imagine -> colta ) ); 
/*I tried with both *imagine ->colta and imagine -> colta just to be safe */
```

The problem shows when I try accessing the fields in the Color table

```
imagine -> colta [ index ].r = r;
```

Maybe it's just a small mistake I made, but I cannot find it. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you! :)

**EDIT**

The code in the main function to this extent is this:

```
XPM *img;
initXPM(img, 10, 10, 1, 3);
setXPMColor(img, 0, 255, 255, 255, "0");
```

The setXPMColor function goes like this:

```
void setXPMColor(XPM *imagine,
    unsigned int index,
    unsigned char r,
    unsigned char g,
    unsigned char b,
    char *charpattern) {


   imagine -> colta [ index ].r = r;
   imagine -> colta [ index ].g = g;
   imagine -> colta [ index ].b = b;
   imagine -> colta [ index ].pchars = charpattern;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof ( imagine -> colta )` is `sizeof(Color*)`, shoud be `sizeof(Color)`

Comment: As I wrote in the line comment, I tried with sizeof(*imagine->colta) too. I also tried with sizeof(Color) but the program still crashes. If I comment the line that accesses imagine -> colta [index].r, all is well

Comment: I tried it also, but it won't change the fact that it still crashes

Comment: In another location if the cause. `initXPM(img, 10, 10, 1, 3);
` Pointer Note that it is passed by value. (Not able to update)

Comment: img is initialized as a pointer. When I pass it to initXPM(img, 10, 10, 1, 3), I pass it as a XPM* type. SO it is okay, right?

Comment: no, So it is not possible to update the content(`img`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void func(type *pointer){
    //"type *pointer" : The only variable on the stack
    pointer = malloc(sizeof(type));//But is not set to the original.
    retrurn;
}
```

short test code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init_int_pointer(int *p){
    p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
}

int main(){
    int *p = NULL;
    printf("before : %p\n", (void*)p);//NULL
    init_int_pointer(p);
    printf("after : %p\n", (void*)p);//NULL

    return 0;
}
```

to fix

```
1)
type * func(){
    type *pointer = malloc(sizeof(type));
    retrurn pointer;
}
...
type *p = func();

2)
void func(type **pointer){
    *pointer = malloc(sizeof(type));
    retrurn ;
}
...
type *p;
func(&p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `sizeof` usage is wrong, `sizeof ( imagine -> colta )` is the size of the pointer.

You mean:

```
imagine->colta = malloc(ncolors * sizeof *imagine->colta);
                                         ^
                                         |
                                    important!
```

Note the asterisk, which makes it mean "the size of the data pointed at by this pointer", i.e. `sizeof (Color)`.

Also, make sure the allocations actually succeed, of course.

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

**UPDATE**:

Your problem seems to be in how you call the function that initializes the structures; you're dropping the top-level `malloc()`ed `XPM` pointer:

```
XPM *img;
initXPM(img, 10, 10, 1, 3);
setXPMColor(img, 0, 255, 255, 255, "0");
```

it should be something like:

```
XPM *img = initXPM(10, 10, 1, 3);
setXPMColor(img, 0, 255, 255, 255, "0");
```

And of course `initXPM` should `return` the local `imagine` variable, so that the caller gets that pointer.

Comment: I did it that way too, as I wrote in the above comment. I tried with sizeof(Color) too but to no prevail.
btw: thank you for the casting tip. I recently have read about not having to use it, but sometime I write it out of habit.

Comment: Then there must be something else that's going wrong. This way is the proper one (or with `sizeof (Color)`). Perhaps you should show the code that loads the data.

Comment: I just added an edit to the code. Is there anything else you need?